# Why phpStorm marks an error on valid query

Tags: mysql, phpstorm, code-inspection

I have a query:

```
$this->source->exec("UPDATE `account` AS `m1`,
  (SELECT   `m2`.`id` 
  FROM `account` AS `m2` 
  WHERE `m2`.`userid` = ? AND `m2`.`demo` = 0 
  ORDER BY `m2`.`date` DESC LIMIT 1) AS `m2`
SET `m1`.`default` = '1' 
WHERE  `m1`.`id` = `m2`.`id` AND `m1`.`demo` = 0", $user_id);
```

Now, phpStorm is trowing an error for the ORDER BY in the subquery. The query works perfectly when the code is run. I set MySQL as the SQL dialect in phpStorm.
The error is:

GROUP or HAVING expected, ORDER got.

**How can I fix this error?**

Answer (score 0):

actually phpstorm recognize this `symbol as invalid key when using with php, cz of php doesn't know about`sql` use

If you check you sql with `index.sql` its show like this (without errors)

[image: sql]

so just create test page with `test.sql` and copy your sql code.

then above of the code you can see orange color tab shows(check below image)

[image: head]

click `Configure Data Source`

and click `MySQL` in left side panel(below image)

[image: mysql]

and then `click download` in bottom of the panel(below image)

[image: download]

It will download file(s) relevant your versions

[image: files]

and click `ok`.

now delete the `index.sql` and you can use as same without error.

> **I have tested and work fine to me**

Comment: Thanks for the answer :) I will check it asap

Comment: @user3033886 happy to help as PhpStorm Family :)